# Using SQL Server 2016 R Services over a standalone installation of Microsoft R Server

Tags: sql-server-2016, r

I've been experimenting with SQL Server 2016 and its R Services. I also have a standalone Microsoft R Server installed on my machine. 

What is a good use-case to use SQL Server R Services over a standalone Microsoft R Server, since both feature properties of an enterprise scale R platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible a slightly subjective question but sometimes it's helpful to think of these things in scenarios, for example:

1. A predominantly SQL Server project, run by DBAs/devs (who may or may not know some R).  A data scientist or R professional writes some R for them or they do it themselves and test on their local machines, eg using R Studio or the [Microsoft R IDE](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/machinelearning/2016/03/09/announcing-r-tools-for-visual-studio-2/).  When they are happy with the R, they plug it into their data workflow using `sp_execute_external_script`.  They can easily incorporate this into other stored procedures, SSIS etc.  This might be a good candidate for SQL Server 2016 with R Services.
2. A secure project, the data is in your secured SQL Server and you want to keep the data close to the analytics and not use the cloud.  This might be a good candidate for an on-premise installation of SQL Server 2016 with R Services.
3. A predominantly data science project which requires data but does not require SQL Server access.  This might be a good candidate for Microsoft R Server only.
4. High performance is required for a big data project.  You do not want to share the box with the traditionally memory-hungry SQL Server.  This might be a good candidate for Microsoft R Server only.

Just a few examples there.  What examples can you think of?

HTH

Comment: Thank you for the crisp answer.  I also think that R Services makes it much easier to deploy a solution after it being created. After the R script or model is ready for production use, you can embed the code or model in Transact-SQL stored procedures, and invoke the saved code from an application.  Do you agree with that statement?

Comment: And.. may be you could also answer this question for me: http://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/12108/what-is-the-difference-between-the-3-architectural-components-of-microsoft-r-ser